# How to mount and unmount on windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, mount

I am running a test that includes mounting and unmounting a USB device.

The test is run on both Linux and Windows. Linux is obviously not an issue, but is there a way, preferably by means of Python, to do this on Windows? Or better yet, is there a library that is cross-compatible, and that would do that for each OS?

Answer (score 1):

You may need install `Desktop-Experience package`

try the following code:

```
import platform
if (platform.system()  == "Windows"):
      os.system('PowerShell Mount-DiskImage C:\path\ConsumerPreview-32bit.iso') 
      # as mount operates only in powershell
elif (platform.system() == "Linux"):
      os.system("mount /dev/dvdrom /mount-point")
```

for eject `DisMount-DiskImage C:\path\English.iso`

and for info `Get-DiskImage C:\path\English.iso | Get-Volume`

You can use mount `os.path.join` to join paths.

Comment: where is the shareName path. is this where I want to mount the usb and device name is name of usb?

Comment: Sharename is \mountpoint  Devicename is full path for USB